# inner join for a query?

Tags: mysql

I want to do a sql query and have some problems:

1. I want to salect from table_1 the ID's Where parent_id is the value I have:

   `SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE parent_ID = 'x'`
2. I want to use the ID'S I got in 1. and

   `SELECT FROM table_2 WHERE ID = 'The ID's from Query 1.`

Comment: @Christina - How is this related to WordPress?

Comment: @ Mike I am using it in a wordpress site, to create custom feed from a farum plugin.

Comment: @Christina: I still think it has noting to do with wordpress , but i think what you are looking for is a simple [Subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: Moving to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and Execute

```
Select t1.`id` FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.`id`=t2.`id`
```

Answer (score 2):

As Bainternet mentioned you can do this with a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE parent_ID = 'x')
```

Though your idea to use an inner join is also good (especially since MySQL can be slow when processing subqueries).

```
SELECT t2.* FROM table_2 as t2 INNER JOIN table_1 AS t1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID WHERE t1.parent_ID = 'x'
```

If that's not clear, try looking at the [MySQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) or the [Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html), as Bainternet mentioned. If these examples and the MySQL docs aren't clear enough for you, consider posting more details on exactly what you're trying to do (e.g. include table structures in your question). Also while you might want this information for some WordPress related work you are doing, there's nothing in the question itself that actually ties it to WordPress. So if you have more questions that about MySQL queries in general, then you might want to consider posting them to the [StackOverflow, tagged as mysql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-query).